# How to load modal when button from another modal is clicked

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have a modal and in that modal is a button. I want to load another modal when the button is clicked. How am I going to do it. I actually set `data-toggle` but when I clicked the button, the modal is loaded but cannot be seen. It can only be seen when I closed the parent modal.

Answer (score 0):

You must also dismiss the previous modal with `data-dismiss="modal"`.

```
<a href="#modal-2" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Modal 2</a>
```